# Email setup in my own iphone app

Tags: iphone

I am new to iphone app development, i have created my own app, i want to know whether we can setup the email address for our own app or we have to use only the email that was setup in the iphone. If we can please give me an idea of how to do it.

Thanks in Advance
Akhil

Comment: I don't understand at all. What email?

Comment: I think the author here is trying to find out whether we can send emails from within app using a non-default mail account (default being the one we configure in Settings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mails sent from within app will only use the default mail account in *Settings*.

**EDIT:**
Here is a sample sendEmail() method:

```
-(IBAction) sendEmail{
    if(![MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){
        //show info msg to user
        return;
    }
    MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [controller setSubject:@"Hello"];
    [controller setMessageBody:@"How are you?" isHTML:NO];
    [controller addAttachmentData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImage,0.8) mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"fileName.jpg"];
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release];
}
```

You will need the `addAttachmentData` method for attachments.

You will also need to implement the didFinishWithResult method to discard the MFMail controller

```
-(void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult) result error:(NSError *) error{
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Make sure your the class where you write these methos implements the < MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate > protocol

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Mihir,

At present i am using default setting. can u tell me, how can i attach the files that were present in my app to the mail.

Thanks 
Akhil.

Comment: And I still have a downvote (-1) :( . If was helpful you should atleast upvote it or probably accept the answer ;-)

Comment: Sorry, for that. I forgot to accept the answer, i will up vote it.

Comment: Hi Mihir,

I am using the MFMailComposeViewController, its working good if the file is less than 15MB, but if the file is more than 15MB its not even getting attached to the mail. What to do for the files more than 15MB. Is there any other way to do for it.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: 15MB is quite a bit of data and I am not surprised Apple has put up this limit on a resource constrained device like iPhone.

1. Dunno how your application is designed but one option is to split the file into smaller chunks and send multiple emails. 

2. Or you can try zipping it up before attaching

3. Or, if possible, you can transfer the attachment to some webserver and email the link to the users

Post this as a separate question so even others are able to provide their input

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [SKPSMTPMessage](http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/) framework for this.  I've used it a few times, and it works OK.  I would recommend using apple's method though

Answer (score 0):

You can open sockets to any server / port you wish and perform whatever actions you want to take. If you run your own SMTP mail server, you could accept "emails" from your own applications pretty easily:

```
EHLO <some identifier>
MAIL FROM: <identifier@domain>
RCPT TO: <destination@domain>
DATA
email goes here
QUIT
```

See [RFC 2821](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt) for details.